# How to import random so I can use random.choice in my function

Tags: python, function, import

My friends and I are working on a text based adventure game.

We tried to make a drop function that uses `random.choice` to pick whether the dropped gear will be common, uncommon or rare.

I have been working on this but I can not seem to get it to work when I call it.

```
from random import *
def drop_get():
com_boots = 2 #speed
com_sword = 3 #attack
com_chest = 3 #health
uncom_boots = 4 #speed
uncom_sword = 6 #attack
uncom_chest = 6 #health
rare_boots = 6 #speed
rare_sword = 9 #attack
rare_chest = 9 #health

drop = random.choice(['Common','Common','Common','Common','Common','Common','Common','Common','Common','Common','Uncommon','Uncommon',
                  'Uncommon','Uncommon','Uncommon','Rare'])

print(drop)
if drop == "Common":
    print("Dang u got bad drop")
elif drop == "Uncommon":
        print("This drop aight")
else:
            print("Noicer u got good drop")

if drop == "Common":
    receive_drop = random.choice(["CommonChest", "CommonSword", "CommonBoots"])
elif drop == "Uncommon":
    receive_drop = random.choice(["UncommonChest", "UncommonSword", "UncommonBoots"])
else:
    receive_drop = random.choice(["RareChest", "RareSword", "RareBoots"])
    print("You have gotten", receive_drop)

    if receive_drop == "CommonChest":
        return com_chest
    elif receive_drop == "CommonBoots":
        return com_boots
    elif receive_drop == "CommonSword":
        return com_sword
    elif receive_drop == "UncommonSword":
        return uncom_sword
    elif receive_drop == "UncommonChest":
        return uncom_chest
    elif receive_drop == "UncommonBoots":
        return uncom_boots
    elif receive_drop == "RareBoots":
        return rare_boots
    elif receive_drop == "RareSword":
        return rare_sword
    elif receive_drop == "RareChest":
        return rare_chest
    drop_get(receive_drop)
drop_get()
```

Comment: Where is your method `drop_get()` defined? Please go through [this tutorial](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html) and you'll understand better.

Comment: What happens when you call the function? How is what actually happens different to what you want to have happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At risk of failing to understand indentation, try:

```
from random import choice
```

Then always call the choice function like this example:

```
drop = choice(['Common','Common','Common','Common','Common','Common','Common','Common','Common','Common','Uncommon','Uncommon', 'Uncommon','Uncommon','Uncommon','Rare'])
```

**Explanation:**
When you use `from random import choice` you just import `choice` and a lot of other functions. It does not import the name of the module at the same time (`random.choice` for example), it only imports the name of the functions, so calling `random.choice` fails, but calling just `choice` works.

This is what happens when you import using **from** keyword. If you just `import random` then you can call stuff like `random.choice`

**Bonus:** 
It's perfectly possible to work using `from random import *` but it's a bad practice. If possible try to keep things simple and just import the methods you are using. If you don't need anything else than `choice` then don't import anything else (* would import `randint`, `randrange` and a lot of unneeded stuff).

Comment: Thanks for the help, i got it to work with this, i'm sorry about the awful indentation, i'm new around here and the whole four space indentation for code on this website kind of confuses me. But once again, thanks for the solution.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Make sure you accept a valid answer clicking on the green tick at the left side of the answer, and please upvote if you find it useful.